# How can I create a Scheduled Task that will run every Second in MarkLogic?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, xquery, marklogic

MarkLogic Scheduled Tasks cannot be configured to run at an interval less than a minute.

Is there any way I can execute an XQuery module at an interval of **1 second**?

**NOTE:**
Considering the situation where the Task Server is fully loaded and I need to make sure that the *secondly scheduled task* gets the Task Server thread whenever it needs.

Please let me know if there is anything in MarkLogic that can be used to achieve this.

Comment: I agree with mblakele, maybe best to rethink what you are trying to do, and ask us how to do that best instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wanting rapid-fire scheduled tasks may be a hint that the design needs rethinking.

Even running a task once a minute can be risky, and needs careful thought to manage the possibilities of overlapping tasks and runaway tasks. If the application design calls for a scheduled task to run once a second, I would raise that as a potentially serious problem. Back up a few steps, and if necessary ask a new question about the higher-level problem that led to looking at scheduled tasks.

There was a sub-question about managing queue priority for tasks. Task priorities can handle some of that. There are two priorities: normal and higher. The Task Server empties the higher-priority queue first, then the normal queue. But each queue is still a simple queue, and there's no way to change priorities after a task has been spawned. So if you always queue tasks with `priority=higher`, then they'll all be in the higher priority queue and they'll all run in order. You can play some games with techniques like using [server fields as signals to already-running tasks](https://github.com/mblakele/taskbot/blob/master/src/taskbot.xqm#L148). But wanting to reorder tasks within a queue could be another hint that the design needs rethinking.

If, after careful thought about all the pitfalls and dangers, I decided I needed a rapid-fire task of some kind.... I would probably do it using external requests. Pick any scripting language and write a simple `while` loop with an HTTP request to the MarkLogic cluster. Even so, spend some time thinking about overlapping requests and locking. What happens if the request times out on the client side? Will it keep running on the server? Will that lead to overlapping requests and require deadlock resolution? Could it lead to runaway resource consumption?

Avoid any ideas that use `xdmp:sleep`. That will tie up a Task Server thread during the sleep period, and then you'll have two problems.